# WD TV Live HD and Solaris

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, bonjour, cifs, zeroconf

Since a few months I own a WD TV Live HD media player and I'm pretty satisfied with it. The performance is good and it's quite stable.

But from the beginning I had issues with the CIFS implementation of Solaris (and all the flavors of it) and the WD TV Live HD as a CIFS client. I simply can't access a share which is shared using the Kernel CIFS implementation of Solaris. I followed the official OpenSolaris CIFS guide so far but still no luck. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/opensolaris-nas-142265.html for details.

Has anybody experience using a ZFS/Solaris flavored NAS system and this client? I tried also the newest beta firmware of the WD Live TV HD and Solaris 11 Express which was released yesterday.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
I solved the issue using the avahi zeroconf daemon to propagate the CIFS service to the client.